# Reload data in WKInterface Table + Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

I am working on watch kit app. Here I want to highlight the selected row in table. My problem is when I select the row the image which is added to row is download again or you can say that list is  blinked. I want only the row which I select update.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from the `delegate`methode of `UITableView` :

If your image is already there, just update/highlight you row or whatever you want.

Overwhise download the image.

```
if (cell.myImage == nil)
  {
    // Download your image
  }
else
  {
    // Reload your cell
  }
```

Also you can rewrite the methode `shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath` (still from the `delegate`of `UITableView`) and make sure to return `YES` if you want to highlight your row :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

If I'm wrong or if I missunderstood the question you asked do not hesitate to let me know.

Comment: Thank you Victor. But in apple watch these delegate methods are not working. I solved the issue...But you try very well..:)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't know that fact -until now-. It's great anyway that you could solve your problem.